# Using a Service Worker in a Quasar SPA

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a functioning Bootstrap app which uses a **Service Worker** for background processing and I'm now rewriting this app as a **Quasar** SPA.  Everything is pretty much working, but I can't figure out how to wrangle Quasar/Webpack to provide the Service Worker file.  *Note that I'm trying to create an SPA and not a PWA*.

I *think* the problem is that I need to tell Quasar/Webpack to provide an unmangled version of the service worker file and name.

So assume my service worker is:

```
// src/modules/sw.js
import * as moment from "moment";
console.log(`From worker: worker started at ${moment().format("HH:mm:ss")}`);
...
```

and I'm trying to load this service worker:

```
// src/modules/foo.js
let worker = new Worker("/modules/sw.js");
```

results in the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://localhost:44444/modules/sw.js
```

and indeed, there is no `sw.js` anywhere in dist if I run `quasar build`.

In the spirit of 10 million monkeys with typewriters trying to write a Shakespeare play I tried adding an entry to `quasar.conf.js`, but this had no beneficial effect:

```
sourceFiles: {
  serviceWorker: 'src/modules/sw.js'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this recently for my Quasar SPA app. The solution consists of 3 pieces:

1. In my frontend (client) code: Registering the service worker and subscribing to push notifications - currently this
   code resides in the created() part of my Quasar main layout (my-layout.vue).
   The service worker registration refers to the service worker path as described in step #2 below:

   const registration =
   await navigator.serviceWorker.register("statics/service-worker.js")
   .then(registration => {return registration})
   .catch(error => console.error("Error in registration:", error)
   );
2. Client side Service Worker code - I placed this .js file temporarily in the /statics folder of my
   frontend code. This piece of code receives the push notifcations and does
   showNotification() to display the notification message on the client. The reason for
   your error above is that the /modules folder isn't the right location for the service worker.
3. Backend (server) code: This piece of code is still experimental, it fires a sendNotification()
   using the NPM web-push package, as described further below.

You need a lot of little things to be set up correctly. The above overall design is most important.

Important for 3.: The objects that are passed into the sendNotification() call on the server:

- pushSubscription object (this has a field "endpoint" and 2 sub-fields for keys which
  are
  output params of the subscription call in 1. on the client). For production level code you
  would have to send those from the client to your database and store them there, e.g. as
  part of user info, then retrieve them from there. My prototype server code currently uses
  copies of those values from the client (browser log) just to get going.
- payload object - this has to be a string holding JSON (use JSON.stringify)
- options object with vapidDetails, which includes public and private key (= output from
  one-time command line action> web-push generate-vapid-keys)

Other important things to observe:

- Service workers work only with https, not with http
- Each push notification from the server goes to a single client, so if you want to
  broadcast to all clients, you need to iterate through all their subscriptions (therefore
  my comment above to store this information in your database)
- In a SPA, you can't easily use Quasar functions in the service worker code. There is
  better Quasar/Service Worker integration for PWAs.
- Browsers cache service worker code, so you need to restart the browser quite frequently
  during testing. Better place a console.log("Here is service worker version x.y") as the
  first statement in your service worker to be able to easily verify in the log that the browser has loaded the right
  code version.
- Service workers are still classified as an "experimental" browser function.

I can paste in code snippets for those pieces, but it is quite a few lines of code, so I'll do that only if you ask for it. Overall, I found web push notifications a bit hard to set up, compared to what they provide. I'm now consdering to use web sockets instead of web push notifications.

Comment: Hi, I would like to have some code snippets please. I'm currently on quasar pwa app, and would like to use service worker, but i'm pretty lost. Thanks